# Delphi 10.2.3 Android apps do not run on Lenovo Tab3

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Applications compiled with Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo do not start on Lenovo Tab3 7 Essential. This applies to any application, demo or even blank. There is an exception on startup in `Android.JNIBridge` at the  `dispatchToNative()` function.

This only happens on Lenovo Tab3 7 Essential. There is no problem running on other devices: Samsung, Huawei, or some cheap tablets. I have a problem only with Lenovo.

Funny thing is that applications compiled with older Delphi 10.1 Berlin or 10.2 Tokyo run perfectly. The problem started with 10.2.2 and continues with 10.2.3.

Exception is at

```
AType := AContext.GetType(AObject.ClassInfo);
```

I have no idea where to look for a solution.

Comment: Isn't this something for the vendor to address. I'm sure they offer support.

Comment: If you mean Lenovo then I'm sure that they will say that this is not their problem. I am asking if anyone had the same problem and knows workaround

Comment: No, I mean the vendor of your compiler

Comment: I created a bug report at Embarcadero but still waiting

Comment: OK, well you should keep waiting then. I don't see why you should also be posting a question here.

Comment: Well . Is there anything wrong in asking community? Some problems have simple solutions, but big companies like Embarcadero need more time to repair. If someone can help why not ask?

Comment: I just don't think that SO is really the appropriate place for such a transient and localized issue. I'd rather you took this to the G+ delphi devs community where i believe you'd be much more likely to get help.

Comment: You have the source, the device, and the ability to use the debugger. If you can't find the problem, then file a bug report at EMBT. We can't do anything to help you here. The [help/on-topic] says that questions asking for debugging help must include a specific problem description, sufficient source (in the form of a [mcve]) to reproduce the problem, and a specific question. You haven't provided that [mcve], and even if you did it's unlikely that someone here will have the exact device and Android version to use to reproduce the issue.

Comment: IMHO an empty app not running on the particular device IS the minimal, complete, and verifiable example. It can be hard to verify without hardware, but certainly all of us having this Lenovo tablet cound generate an empty project and test it, don't you think so? In fact, the problem seems to be broader, there are some Android devices causing troubles with Tokyo, especially Google Glass. I did not manage to determine the actual reason of the problem, but the more people discuss it, the bigger is hope to fix the problem. I think that it is the aim of community disscusion and SO in general ;)